# is there a way to fix this wordpress slider issue?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, slider

so I'm trying to learn a bit more about WordPress developing and I'm having issues with the slider,
the photos that should be in the slider are stacked on top of each other and the slider itself showing up at the extreme left of the site

this is my functions.php so far:

```
<?php
function roofgrow_files() {
wp_enqueue_script('roofgrow-js', get_theme_file_uri('/build/index.js'), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
wp_enqueue_style('custom-google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i|Roboto:100,300,400,400i,700,700i');
wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('roofgrow_main_styles', get_theme_file_uri('/build/style-index.css'));
wp_enqueue_style('roofgrow_main_styles', get_theme_file_uri('/build/index.css'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'roofgrow_files');
?>
```

and the part of the slider in my index.php:

```
 <div class="hero-slider">
      <div data-glide-el="track" class="glide__track">
        <div class="glide__slides">
          <div class="hero-slider__slide" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images/bus.jpg') ?>)">
            <div class="hero-slider__interior container">
              <div class="hero-slider__overlay">
                <h2 class="headline headline--medium t-center">Free Transportation</h2>
                <p class="t-center">yee.</p>
                <p class="t-center no-margin"><a href="#" class="btn btn--blue">Learn more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="hero-slider__slide" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images/apples.jpg')?>)">
            <div class="hero-slider__interior container">
              <div class="hero-slider__overlay">
                <h2 class="headline headline--medium t-center">An Apple a Day</h2>
                <p class="t-center">Our dentistry program recommends eating apples.</p>
                <p class="t-center no-margin"><a href="#" class="btn btn--blue">Learn more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="hero-slider__slide" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('images/bread.jpg')?>)">
            <div class="hero-slider__interior container">
              <div class="hero-slider__overlay">
                <h2 class="headline headline--medium t-center">Free Food</h2>
                <p class="t-center">blah blah test.</p>
                <p class="t-center no-margin"><a href="#" class="btn btn--blue">Learn more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__bullets glide__bullets" data-glide-el="controls[nav]"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

was looking for a solution for hours and didn't find any, so any suggestions or help, in general, would be appreciated

Comment: Rightclick on the image, then inspect. Look at the CSS on the right

Comment: @mplungjan the transform: translate3d px numbers are changing all the time, and when I disable it in element.style it looks good for a second and then comes back to normal :(